# Removing empty xml nodes

Tags: python

I have an xml file that I'm trying to remove empty nodes from with python. When I've tested it to check if a the value is, say, 'shark', it works. But when i check for it being none, it doesn't remove the empty node.

```
for records in recordList:
        for fieldGroup in records:
            for field in fieldGroup:
                if field.text is None:
                    fieldGroup.remove(field)
```

Comment: Please provide example input and output documents.

Comment: can you print `field.text` to see if the value is truly None?  It could be an empty string or a string with spaces / new line characters.  They would evaluate to false when compared against None.

Answer (score 2):

[xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) is your friend here.

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.XML("""<root><a>1</a><b><c></c></b><d></d></root>""")

def remove_empty_elements(doc):
  for element in doc.xpath('//*[not(node())]'):
    element.getparent().remove(element)
```

Then:

```
>>> print etree.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
<root>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>
    <c/>
  </b>
  <d/>
</root>

>>> remove_empty_elements(doc)
>>> print etree.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
<root>
  <a>1</a>
  <b/>
</root>

>>> remove_empty_elements(doc)
>>> print etree.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
<root>
  <a>1</a>
</root>
```

Answer (score -2):

For the benefit of others, I'd like to share this.

I trawled various posts and articles attempting to find something that would remove empty nodes from the query results I wrote, but I think it could be used in this instance also.

```
modify('delete //modules[fn:not(.//text()) = xs:boolean("true")]')
```

To give some context, the query brought back many empty  nodes and I wanted to clean it up.

After populating a XML variable, @textXML, I removed the empty modules nodes using:

```
    set @testXML.modify('delete //modules[fn:not(.//text()) = xs:boolean("true")]')

    select @testXML;
```